# Ejecutar proyecto java con el modulo node-jre

Tags: java, nodejs

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación node desde la que necesito ejecutar código java.

Estoy usando el modulo: node-jre (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jre).

El ejemplo que viene en la pagina (Hello.class) me funaciona bien con el codigo que viene en la pagina (a continuación lo incluyo) pero compilado la clase por consola con: *javac Hello.java*:

```
    var output = jre.spawnSync(  // call synchronously 
    ['java'],                // add the relative directory 'java' to the class-path 
    'Hello',                 // call main routine in class 'Hello' 
    ['World'],               // pass 'World' as only parameter 
    { encoding: 'utf8' }     // encode output as string 
  ).stdout.trim();
```

El problema viene cuando trato de ejecutar un proyecto que he creado en eclipse. La documentacion dice que en el directorio 'java' busca en los ficheros jar, asi que yo he probado a exportar el proyecto como .jar, pero no funciona, parece que no encuentra la clase principal que es la que le paso.

Así que, esa es la pregunta ¿cómo puedo hacer para ejecutar mi proyecto java con node-jre?

Creo que es importante decir que el proyecto tiene libreras externas y también un único paquete con 7 clases de las cuales solo una es la principal (tiene método main).

Comment: Hi, this is spanish site, please translate your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución:

```
var output = jre.spawnSync(  // call synchronously 
        ['java/hello.jar'],                // add the relative directory 'java' to the class-path 
        'com.package.example.Hello',                 // call main routine in class 'Hello' 
        ['World'],               // pass 'World' as only parameter 
        { encoding: 'utf8' }     // encode output as string 
      ).stdout.trim();
```

- Ruta completa al fichero jar
- El nombre de la clase principal con toda los paquetes (separando con .)

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación del módulo que estás ocupando

```
 classpath (array of strings). Paths to .jar files or directories containing .classfiles.
```

Tienes que poner tus clases Java que vas a utilizar(.class) y los .jar de las bibliotecas(erróneamente llamadas librerías en español) externas que vas a ocupar. Recuerda que el classpath es la forma en que Java sabe de donde tomar los jar para la ejecución.

Sobre el package recuerda que solo debes agregar los .class que son las clases compiladas de Java. Si vas a dejar la estructura del package(que en realidad son carpetas) entonces imagino debes llamarlas en base al nombre de package. Es decir si tu Main Class está en

```
com/ferroblesh/Main.class
```

Deberías llamarlo por su nombre con el package:

```
var output = jre.spawnSync(  // call synchronously 
  ['java'],                  // add the relative directory 'java' to the class-path 
  'com.ferroblesh.Main',     // call main routine in class 'Hello' 
  ['World'],                 // pass 'World' as only parameter 
  { encoding: 'utf8' }       // encode output as string 
).stdout.trim();
```

Comment: De acuerdo con que se debe llamar *biblioteca* en lugar de *librería*. Yo uso mucho el segundo por costumbre, pero habrá que corregir.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! La solución era poner la ruta completa del fichero .jar

Comment: Que bueno que funcionó. Te agradecería el voto positivo :) Saludos